# Find the radius of circle $P$

Tags: geometry

> $ABCD$ is a rectangle with $AB = CD = 2$. A circle centered at $O$ is tangent to $BC, CD,$ and $AD$ (and hence has radius $1$). Another circle, centered at $P$, is tangent to circle $O$ at point $T$ and is also tangent to $AB$ and $BC$. If line $AT$ is tangent to both circles at $T$, find the radius of circle $P$.

Can someone create a picture for this? I am having a hard time seeing how the circle centered at $P$ can be tangent to the circle centered at $O$.

Comment: $AT=\phi.$ See [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want a picture as an answer, or a solution as an answer, but here's a picture (roughly to scale, but no promises):

[image]

Comment: Doe the big circle centered at $O$ need to be contained within the rectangle?

Comment: I don't see anything in the problem description that mandates that.  However, if you have $BC = AD < 2$, then either circle $P$ is externally tangent to circle $O$ (but then there is no way for $\overline{AT}$ to be tangent to both circles), or else it is internally tangent to circle $O$, but then $T$ must be the tangent point in common between circle $O$, circle $P$, and $\overline{BC}$ (and again there is no way for $\overline{AT}$ to be tangent to both circles).

Comment: Yes, since the circle centered at $O$ is tangent to $BC$, $CD$ and $AD$ the only side of the rectangle that can cut said circle is $AB$ (as long as $CB > 1$). If that is the case, the only option for the circle centered at $P$ to be tangent to $AB$, $BC$ and the first circle is if both circles' tangent point with $BC$ is the same (which would be $T$), but then $AT$ wouldn't be tangent to either circle.

Comment: @DarthGeek So the question implies this configuration?

Comment: Indirectly, yes.  It is the only configuration, I believe, that produces a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Let us assume that @Briantung ‘s diagram is correct. If we identity the lengths of the line segments starting from D (in anti-clockwise direction), we will have the following diagram.

[image]

Then,  $1 + 2x + y = BC = AD = 1 + 2 – y$.

This implies $x + y = 1$ ......... (*)

Now let draw some more lines (like MV and SR) to analyze the lengths of some segments. (Please refer to the second diagram.)

[image]

If the (*) is true, NS has to be y. Then, SU = x – y, RA = SB = SU + UB = (x – y) + y = x.

Thus, the tangent NM = NT = NU = x = RA.

Adopting this result, we construct the second circle as follows:-

1) Draw the line SR such that CDRS is a square of side 2.

2) Translate RA to MN such that RA = MN = x.

Then, NA should be our common tangent to the 2 circles with the point of contact at T. My third diagram clearly shows that it is not the case.

[image]